# Update multiple rows, but only first row with different value

Tags: mysql, join

table

```
create table tst(locationId int,
                 scheduleCount tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
                 displayFlag tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0);

INSERT INTO tst(locationId,scheduleCount)
values(5,0),(2,0),(5,1),(5,2),(2,1),(2,2);
```

I update multiple rows and multiple columns with one query, but want to change the one of the columns only for the first row and keep the other things the same for that column.

I want to update all the rows with some location id and change displayFlag to 1 and increment scheduleCount of only the top entry with 1 , rest would remain the same

**Query **

```
update tst,(select @rownum:=0) r,
       set tst.displayFlag =1, 
       scheduleCount = (CASE WHEN @rownum=0
                             then scheduleCount+1
                             ELSE scheduleCount
                        END), 
       @rownum:=1 where locationId = 5
```

But it gives error and does not set the user defined variable **rownum**, I am able to join the tables in a select and change the value of the rownum, is there any other way to update the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the correct way of doing such a thing, but it is possible to include the user variable logic in the `CASE` condition:

```
UPDATE tst
  JOIN (SELECT @first_row := 1) r
   SET tst.displayFlag = 1, 
       scheduleCount = CASE 
         WHEN @first_row = 1 AND ((@first_row := 0) OR TRUE) THEN scheduleCount+1
         ELSE scheduleCount
       END
 WHERE locationId = 5;
```

I have used a `@first_row` flag as this is more inline with your initial attempt.

The `CASE` works as follows:

- On the first row `@first_row = 1` so the second part of the `WHEN` after `AND` is processed, setting `@first_row := 0`. Unfortunately for us, the assignment returns `0`, hence the `OR TRUE` to ensure the condition as a whole is `TRUE`. Thus `scheduleCount + 1` is used.
- On the second row `@first_row != 1` so the condition is `FALSE`, the second part of the `WHEN` after `AND` is not processed and the `ELSE scheduleCount` is used.

You can see it working in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b5e7/1). Note; I have had to set the column types to `TINYINT(3)` to get the correct results.

**N.B.** Without an `ORDER BY` there is no guarantee as to what the '1st' row will be; not even that it will be the 1st as returned by a `SELECT * FROM tst`.

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately one cannot add an `ORDER BY` if there is a join.. so you have a choice:

Initialise `@first_row` outside the query and remove the `JOIN`.

Otherwise you are probably better off rewriting the query to something similar to:

```
UPDATE tst
  JOIN (
    SELECT locationId,
           scheduleCount,
           displayFlag,
           @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS row_number
      FROM tst 
      JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0) init
     WHERE locationId = 5
  ORDER BY scheduleCount DESC
       ) tst2
    ON tst2.locationId = tst.locationId 
   AND tst2.scheduleCount = tst.scheduleCount 
   AND tst2.displayFlag = tst.displayFlag 
   SET tst.displayFlag = 1, 
       tst.scheduleCount = CASE  
         WHEN tst2.row_number = 1 THEN tst.scheduleCount+1
         ELSE tst.scheduleCount
       END;
```

Or write two queries:

```
  UPDATE tst
     SET displayFlag = 1
   WHERE locationId = 5;

  UPDATE tst
     SET scheduleCount = scheduleCount + 1 
   WHERE locationId = 5
ORDER BY scheduleCount DESC
   LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It works, can you explain the case statement , i am not able to get that clearly

Comment: And i intend to add order by to the update query, would that work

Comment: i get incorrect usage of update and order by when using a order by in the query

Comment: Thanks, i used a variation of the first query, and if there is a unique id field, then we can do the update join on that field alone right?